# Scandir Own filter function

Tags: c, linux, scandir

I must write  2 functions, filter - names > 5 chars  and I must sort them by types.

Filtr function should look like this ?

```
int (* filter) (const struct dirent* entry) {

    if ( (strlen(entry>d_name) - 1 ) > 5 ) {
        return entry;
    }
}
```

How about sort, in dirent its dirent->d_type, but how to sort ?

Comment: just `int filter(const struct dirent *entry)`... you pass a function pointer to `scandir()`, but the filter function itself isn't declared as a pointer.

Comment: `return entry` is not correct. The return type is `int`, so I assume you're supposed to return 0 or 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered taking a look at the [`man 3 scandir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html) page?

(I find the [Linux man-pages project](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html) man pages most up-to-date for C library and system level programming.)

If we have a function that needs the caller to specify a helper function our function should call to do some task, we declare it as a *function pointer*. In other words, while the prototype for the `scandir()` function is

```
int scandir(const char *dirp, struct dirent ***namelist,
            int (*filter)(const struct dirent *),
            int (*compar)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **));
```

the prototypes for the filter and comparison functions are actually

```
int myfilter(const struct dirent *);
int mycompar(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **);
```

Silly implementations for the functions (that do not fulfill your exercise requirements) could be for example

```
int myfilter(const struct dirent *entry)
{
    /* man 3 scandir says "entries for which filter()
     * returns nonzero are stored".
     *
     * Since file names in Linux are multibyte strings,
     * we use mbstowcs() to find out the length
     * of the filename in characters.
     *
     * Note: strlen() tells the filename length in bytes,
     *       not characters!
    */
    const size_t len = mbstowcs(NULL, entry->d_name, 0);

    /* Keep filenames that are 3 or 7 characters long. */
    return (len == 3) || (len == 7);
}

int mycompar(const struct dirent **entry1, const struct dirent **entry2)
{
    const size_t len1 = mbstowcs(NULL, (*entry1)->d_name, 0);
    const size_t len2 = mbstowcs(NULL, (*entry2)->d_name, 0);

    /* Compare by file name lengths (in characters),
     * sorting shortest file names first. */
    return (int)((ssize_t)len1 - (ssize_t)len2);
}
```

When writing code using POSIX.1-2008, remember to add

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

before any `#include`s. To make your code work correctly in different environments (for example, counting **characters** instead of **bytes** in file names, in any Linux system around our world), also `#include <locale.h>`, and add

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

in your `main()` before you read/scan or write/print anything. (Although there is lots more one *can* do to localize their programs even further, the above very often suffices. Processing text files should be done using wide strings (`L"This is a ωide §tring liteℛal "`) and the `wchar_t` and `wint_t` types for strings and characters, with the wide string I/O functions. It isn't any more complex or hard to do right, than doing it in the idiotic *"The twenty-seven ASCII letters are sufficient for everyone, even if it makes your name into a dirty word in your native language"* way.

If your teacher does not mention these, you should ask why. A program that cannot handle files or text `Nöminäl Änimäl needs more €, and cowbell`, correctly, should not be acceptable in this day and age. There is no need to first learn *a wrong way* to do things before learning the right way, because the right way is just as easy as the wrong way is.